# How to fix the IMAP Self Certification Error in Node12

Tags: node.js, certificate

If you're getting issues with imap self certification signing, and don't want to use NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED.

This solution does the trick

```
imap = new Imap({
    host: host
    tls: true
    tlsOptions: { servername: host }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the servername like below and the error will go away.

```
imap = new Imap({
    host: host
    tls: true
    tlsOptions: { servername: host }
})
```